# Creating a invisible PDF object with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I have a program that outputs to PDF, however, I want it to be able to read from it.

I have come up with my own data type which my program is able to read, but I need it somehow included in PDF file (no multiple files, I want one file per single output).
I also need this data to be invisible and undetectable for the user.

I heard something about PDF dictionaries, but I'm not sure how to do it (or if there's another way). I do not want to use XMP/XML file, my data is more complex than key-value.

What would be nice is somebody writing me couple example lines of code that would enable me to:

- add new dicitonary to PDF using iText
- populate it with data using iText
- locate it in a file using iText
- read from it using iText

Comment: XML can store very complex data and it usually does

Comment: Is there a way to embedd it to PDF in a way that it won't be visible to user?

Answer (score 3):

You want to do something similar to what Adobe Illustrator is doing. If you create a PDF from Adobe Illustrator, you can encapsulate the original AI file. This gives you the impression the PDF can be edited. In reality, Adobe Illustrator takes the AI file and uses that to edit, and re-creates the PDF from the updated AI.

Where is this information stored? See ISO-32000-1 section 14.5:

> Conforming products may use this dictionary as a place to store
>   private data in connection with that document, page, or form. Such
>   private data can convey information meaningful to the conforming
>   product that produces it (such as information on object grouping for a
>   graphics editor or the layer information used by Adobe Photoshop®) but
>   may be ignored by general-purpose conforming readers.

I'm not sure what is asked here. If you're asking for advice like what I answered above: for instance add a PieceInfo entry to the Root dictionary (aka Catalog). This is all documented, isn't it? Read the ISO specification, and read part 4 of "iText in Action".

If your question is: *write some code for me that does what I need to do.* then I believe that's more or less in violation with the goal of this site.

Comment: fo the last part, I meant something such as: iTextClassINeed.createNewDictionary(args);
iTextClassINeed.addNewlineToDictionary(args);

Then I would go explore iTextClassINeed for any further information...

Comment: My answer implied: DO NOT CREATE A NEW DICTIONARY! Use the syntax that is proposed in ISO-32000-1 and add a Page-Piece Dictionary to the catalog. How? By using PdfWriter.getExtraCatalog() and adding a Piece-Info dictionary. How do you create a Piece-Info dictionary? Er... why not use new PdfDictionary()?

Answer (score 1):

Well you could hex encode your data as a String and then draw it off screen like this:

```
cb.showTextAligned(PdfContentByte.ALIGN_LEFT,"HIDDENDATA_"+ hexencodeddata, 2000f,2000f, 0f);
```

and to read process all string searching for HIDDENDATA_

Another way is to use Annotations

```
 public void addAnnotation(PdfWriter writer,
        Document document, Rectangle rect, String text) {
        PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfAnnotation(writer,
            new Rectangle(
                rect.getRight() + 10, rect.getBottom(),
                rect.getRight() + 30, rect.getTop()));
        annotation.setTitle("Text annotation");
        annotation.put(PdfName.SUBTYPE, PdfName.TEXT);
        annotation.put(PdfName.OPEN, PdfBoolean.PDFFALSE);

        annotation.put(PdfName.NAME, new PdfName(text));
        writer.addAnnotation(annotation);
    }
```

And then use some like this to read it.

http://downloads.snowtide.com/javadoc/PDFTextStream/2.3.2/com/snowtide/pdf/PDFTextStream.html

Comment: I won't vote this down, but this is bad advice: annotations will show up in Adobe Reader. Using hex encoded data and write it outside the visible area of a page is considered 'improper use' of PDF. If ISO-32000-1 provides a mechanism to store private data, why not use if?

Comment: I agree with you, it is just an alternative way. Your previous answer is the best way, but even if PDF supports private data, some times you don't want to advice that there is private data, a more discrete way.